# How to autosize/resize the columns of a table in Lotus using VBA?

Tags: vba, lotus-notes

I am coding up a VBA script to create & email a table of data.  And while it does work, it's also ugly.  One thing I'd like to do is resize these columns so they don't take up the entire width of the page.

The "autosize column" option would be nice, except I don't see anywhere in the API.  Alternatively, I'm open to manually setting the widths of each column.  Can someone tell me what code I need to add?

```
Dim rtNav As NotesRichTextNavigator
Dim rtTbl As NotesRichTextTable
Dim TblHeader_FontStyle As NotesRichTextStyle
Dim TblBody_BackgroundStyle As NotesRichTextStyle
Dim TblHeader_BackgroundStyle As NotesColorObject
Dim TblBody_FontStyle As NotesColorObject

Sub AppendTable()
'Define styles
    Set TblHeader_BackgroundStyle = NtSession.CreateColorObject
        TblHeader_BackgroundStyle.NotesColor = COLOR_DARK_BLUE
    Set TblHeader_FontStyle = NtSession.CreateRichTextStyle
        TblHeader_FontStyle.NotesColor = COLOR_WHITE
        TblHeader_FontStyle.FontSize = 8

    Set TblBody_FontStyle = NtSession.CreateColorObject
        TblBody_FontStyle.NotesColor = COLOR_WHITE
    Set TblBody_BackgroundStyle = NtSession.CreateRichTextStyle
        TblBody_BackgroundStyle.NotesColor = COLOR_BLACK
        TblBody_BackgroundStyle.FontSize = 10
'-----------------------------------------------------
'Make table structure
    NtBod.AppendTable lRowCount:=1, lColumnCount:=5
    Set rtNav = NtBod.CreateNavigator
    Set rtTbl = rtNav.GetFirstElement(RTELEM_TYPE_TABLE)
    rtTbl.Style = TABLESTYLE_TOP
    Call NtBod.AppendStyle(TblHeader_FontStyle)
    Call rtTbl.SetColor(TblHeader_BackgroundStyle)
    rtNav.FindFirstElement (RTELEM_TYPE_TABLECELL)
'The rest of the procedure to navigate the table and insert the data goes here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a parameter in the `AppendTable` method that lets you specify the style for each column, including the width.

From the AppendTable method documentation:

> Call
>   notesRichTextItem.**AppendTable**(rows%,
>   columns% [, labels]  [,leftMargin&] 
>   [, rtpsStyleArray] )
>
> **Parameters:**
>   *rows%*     Integer. Number of rows in the table.
>
> *columns%*      Integer. Number of columns in the table.
>
> *labels*     Array of type String. Optional. Text of labels for a tabbed
>   table. The number of array elements
>   must equal the number of rows.
>   Omitting this parameter appends a
>   basic table. Including this parameter
>   appends a tabbed table.
>
> *leftMargin&*     Long.  Optional. Left margin of the table in twips.
>   Defaults to 1440. The following
>   constants are available:
>
> - RULER_ONE_CENTIMETER (567)
> - RULER_ONE_INCH (1440)
>
> *rtpsStyleArray*     Array of type NotesRichTextParagraphStyle. Optional.
>   Creates a table with fixed-width
>   columns and style attributes as
>   specified. Omitting this parameter
>   creates an auto-width  table. The
>   array must contain one element for
>   each column in the table in sequence.
>   Explicitly set the first line left
>   margin and left margin, which control
>   the start of text  relative to the
>   start of the column, and the right
>   margin, which controls column width.

Comment: That's what I was looking for.  I haven't worked on this code in awhile, so I'm a little rusty.